# Why Renamer in Roslyn doesn't rename AnonymousObjectMemberDeclarator ?

Tags: c#, roslyn

I have the below code and I have renamed with roslyn some symbols for example I changed ID property of Student class to Id but some of referenced of ID doesn't changed.

```
public class Student
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    public List<Student> ListOfStudent { get; set; }
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var List1 = (from s in ListOfStudent select new { s.ID });// s.ID Changed to s.Id
        var List2 = (from s in List1 where s.ID == 0 select s);   // s.ID doesn't Changed to s.Id
    }
}
```

I changed the PropertyDeclarationSyntax in my solution.but I don't know why ID property in above code doesn't change. 
How can i rename it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a known bug as I have also detailed in my own project here: https://github.com/Vannevelj/VSDiagnostics/issues/379

Long story short: the combination of renaming a field that is passed to an anonymous object and used afterwards is a scenario that is currently not handled by Roslyn.

A minified example:

```
var x = 5
var y = new { x };
var z = y.x;
```

If you now rename `x`, you will receive

```
var newName = 5
var y = new { newName };
var z = y.x;
```

which is obviously not compilable.

There isn't much you can do other than writing your own renaming logic. I decided to leave the bug as it is considering my scenario will very rarely occur.

There is an open PR that attempts to handle this (partially?) but it hasn't had traction in a while: https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/pull/5786

Answer (score 3):

'Ctrl + .' and also R# rename its. 
Anyway, I think it's a bug because List1 is `IEnumerable<anonymous type>` and not `IEnumerable<Student>`, the ID property of LIst1 it's not the same ID of your student.

Comment: I want rename it with roslyn not in visual studio

Comment: @mohsen By examine the symbol? If yes, it's not gone to work. Like I said its a different symbol. Anyway you can do it based on another logic like to examine the property type and name.